# Automator viewer can't get device screen shoot

Tags: android-uiautomator

After started android emulator and run an example app. I run the UI Automator Viewer and click button Device Screenshoot and it shows message:

[image]

I've tried to run as administrator but it not successfully!

Comment: What is the SDK level of the device on which you are trying to take screen shot?

Comment: API level 19 (Android 4.4.2)

Comment: I'm using windows 8.1

Comment: were you able to get screenshot of home screen?

Comment: No I can't, It won't work in any screen

Comment: Then it should most probably be the problem with SDK.. try to update/download latest SDK..

Comment: Thanks Anvesh, I don't know what the problem is. But after I pluged in The Samsung Nexus 10 real device and Install its driver, UIAutomator can work right now :) Thank for your help :)

Comment: Good to hear that your work got unblocked.. Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

Looks to an issue with `emulator` configuration and not specific to your `application`, try to play with configuration of your `emulator`